# Restricted isometry property for Subgaussian matrices with non-diagonal covariance?

Tags: compressed-sensing

I was wondering if there were any results on whether the restricted isometry property held for Subgaussian or Gaussian random matrices that had covariance matrices that were not completely diagonal?